# Create third matrix in MATLAB from combination of two other matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, element, bsxfun

I have two expressions in MATLAB that represent a 365x24 matrix. The first expression has 10, 365x24 matrices and is therefore

```
PV_power_output(:,:,K)
```

and the second expression which is again 365x24 but with three possible matrices therefore is

```
WT_energy_supply(:,:,M);ode here
```

Now, I am looking to create a third matrix that adds the elements in the same position above and thus form a 365x24 matrix. However I want a set of matrix with all possible combinations of the two expressions shown above (therefore this matrix must be 365x24x30.

How do I go about this?
What about the [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) function in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the original matrices (which for clarity I name `a` and `b`) with [repmat](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) and then just add them, bsxfun is not needed.

```
repmat(a,[1 1 size(b,3)]) + repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]))
```

**Update**

```
>> size(a)
ans = 
    364  24  10

>> size(b)
ans = 
    364  24  3

>> c=repmat(a,[1 1 size(b,3)])+repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]);
>> size(c)
ans = 
    364  24  30
```

It looks fine to me. Of course you'll have to replace my variables `a` and `b` with your variables `PV_power_output` and `WT_energy_supply`.

Comment: thanks but I can only get a 365x24 matrix this way. how do i access any of the 30 matrices created?